# XNAvs Unity for Developing Kinect games

Tags: xna, unity-game-engine, kinect

I wold like to build a simple 3D game using Kinect for windows but I am confuse about what game engine to use.
 The game that I intend to build has simple graphics and static background however the  accepted user motion need to be accurate .
My question is what is better Unity3D or XNA ?? ANd is there any other game engine you recommends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might also want to consider using [Motion Toolkit](http://u3d.as/content/omek/omek-motion-toolkit/3CP) for Unity. Like OpenNI its not the "official" SDK, and uses a middleware by some company called Omek (At least according to the package description) but it integrated nicely into Unity, and works nicely for me.

Answer (score 1):

Unity3D has no support for the Kinect for Windows SDK (or vice versa). Unity3D uses a version of mono which has a subset of .NET 3.5 - and the KfW SDK is developed for .NET 4 and above. You can get the two working together using C++ interops but its a lengthy process, and not really documented anywhere. OpenNI/NITE has Unity support for Kinect but it is not the "offical" SDK and I'm not 100% sure how redistrubution works.

KfW has fully support for XNA, and samples are now included.

The huge difference however is the development environmenet. XNA is all code based, and provides a game loop and a C# based framework to edit the 3D objects. This means you code everything from scratch and are required to calculate all the math and physics. It's a great platform but has a steep learning curve. 
Unity3D in comparison is a visual tool, allowing you to drag and drop assets, cameras, lighting on the screen to ensure you are getting the correct visual look and feel. You then write scripts and attach them to the assets instead of coding a whole game from the ground up.

In my experience I much prefer Unity for developing 3D games, however now having the full KfW support is always a problem for me. However this is a personal choice and for many scenarios OpenNI works just fine.